# What is correct syntax for select?

Tags: mysql, node.js

In Node.js what is correct syntax for select with two where parameters.

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * FROM id WHERE email=? AND password=?', [e] , [p],                 
    function(err, rows){

          if (err){
            throw err;
          }else{
            for (var i in rows) {
               console.log('name: ', rows[i].name);
               open("http://localhost:9383/tweets");

            }
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to include multiple parameters inside the bracket separated by a comma

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM id WHERE email=? AND password=?', [e, p], function(err, rows){...});
```

see [DOCUMENTATION](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)

search for `Alternatively, you can use ??` on the page, and the code block will be right below there for an example.

**BONUS:**

two question marks means its an identifier so you can specify table names like that if you would like.

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE email=? AND password=?', ['id', e, p], function(err, rows){...});
```